# Not able to redirect with href

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have simple spring project and two jsp pages (index.jsp and login.jsp) and there is href in login.jsp to redirect to index.jsp. But i am not able to redirect and getting error HTTP Status 404 the requested resource is not available.
Please find the attached code:

**Homecontroller.java**

```
package n.k.p;

import java.text.DateFormat;    
import java.util.Date;    
import java.util.Locale;    
import org.slf4j.Logger;    
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;    
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;    
import org.springframework.ui.Model;    
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;    
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller

public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);           
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);         
        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );           
        return "login";
    }       
}
```

**login.jsp**

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Registration</title>
</head>

<body>

    <form method="post" action="registration.jsp">

        <table border="1" width="30%" cellpadding="5">

            <thead>

                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">Enter Information Here</th>
                </tr>

            </thead>

            <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td>First Name</td>

                    <td><input type="text" name="fname" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name</td>

                    <td><input type="text" name="lname" value="" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Email</td>

                    <td><input type="text" name="email" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>User Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="uname" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="pass" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>

                    <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">Already registered!! <a href="index.jsp">Login Here</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: what url you are seeing in browser?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/p/index.jsp

Comment: yes while starting the project i am getting url ( localhost:8080/p/ ) and this is my login page and it is working fine but there is one href i am using inside login page as you can see above, while clicking that href i am getting url ( localhost:8080/p/pindex.jsp ) with the error resource not found.

Comment: where do you keep jsp file? You access login.jsp with \@RequestMapping . if you access index.jsp, use other \@RequestMaping for index.jsp.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `redirect` from jsp page to another you can use function `javascript` like this:

```
   ....
  <a href="login.jsp">Login Here</a>
 </form>
 ...
<script>
$('#form a').click(function(e)
{
   e.preventDefault();
  var destination = $(this).attr('href');
   $('#form').attr('action', destination);
   $('#form').submit();
 });
</script>
```

But if you want rediret from controller try to use this:

```
    return "redirect:/login.jsp";
```

If you prefer to use `JSTL` in yuor jsp page:

```
   <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

   <body>
    <c:redirect url="/login.jsp"/>
    </body>
```

Comment: but for redirecting from one JSP to another always mapping is required inside controller

Comment: @Amit Kumar you want redirecting from controller or from page jsp

Comment: yes i want linking one jsp to another jsp and that is what i am trying to do, but not able to do so. And Mohammad Faisal is suggesting that we need to write mapping inside the controller.

Comment: I want redirection from JSP page